# Expiring JWT in Auth0

Tags: jwt, auth0

I am of opinion that JWT tokens once created will expire as per the "exp" claim set on the token, there is no other way to force a token to expire before the expiration time occurs (so keep the token shortlived, renew as required); Recently I came to know when the JWT is generated out of auth0 server, JWT tokens can indeed be force expired by invoking /logout endpoint; I am unsure about how can this be possible as JWT token will continue to be the same and JWT verification will still turn valid (within the expiration timelimit); can someone with Auth0 experience shed some light?

Comment: Where did you read that JWT can be expired on logout?

Comment: @Rezaa91 from this link: https://auth0.com/docs/logout/log-users-out-of-auth0